# AgGrid setFrameworkBeans is not a function

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using a trial enterprise version of ag-Grid v 8.0.0 in react.
 I have installed ag-grid-react v8.0.0 and have set the license. If I try to create an Ag grid react using

```
<AgGridReact
 rowData= {this.props.events}
 enableSorting="true"
 enableFilter="true"
 rowHeight="22"
 columnDefs = {{headerName : "Report Status" , field:"Report Status"}}
 />
```

it gives me the error

```
uncaught TypeError: AgGrid.Grid.setFrameworkBeans is not a function
```

I am not able to debug the actual cause

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you're installing the enterprise dependency, you may also need to install ag-grid too.

ag-grid is a peer dependency of ag-grid-enterprise so if you're using npm for example you'll need to have something like this in package.json:

`"dependencies": {
    "react": "0.14.6",
    "react-dom": "0.14.6",
    "ag-grid": "8.0.x",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "8.0.x",
    "ag-grid-react": "8.0.x"
  }`